# Getting rid of 'command' argument in help of custom Symfony command call

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to write a console command that takes several optional options, but one of them are required. If none of the options have a value, I want to print the command's help description. This is working fine with one exception - when I call the 'help' command manually, a 'command' argument shows up on the help screen.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class TestCommand extends Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setName('test')
      ->setDescription('A test command.')
      ->setHelp('Help message.')
      ->addOption('one', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Option 1', null)
      ->addOption('two', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Option 2', null);
  }

  public function execute(InputInterface $in, OutputInterface $out)
  {
    $helpCommand = $this->getApplication()->get('help');
    $helpCommand->run(new ArrayInput(['command_name' => $this->getName()]), $out);
    return 0;
  }
}

$app = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
$app->add(new TestCommand());
$app->run();
```

Below is the output of `help test`:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/sf2-console-test
$ ./run.php help test
Usage:
 test [--one[="..."]] [--two[="..."]]

Options:
 --one                 Option 1
 --two                 Option 2
...
```

Compared to the output of just `help`:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/sf2-console-test
$ ./run.php test
Usage:
 test [--one[="..."]] [--two[="..."]]

Arguments:
 command               The command to execute

Options:
 --one                 Option 1
 --two                 Option 2
...
```

Is there a way to get rid of the 'command' argument?

The 'command' argument is part of Applicaiton::getDefaultInputDefinition, but I've tried `$this->getApplication()->getDefinition()->setArguments([]);` right before calling the help command and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Tested with symfony/console v2.4.2 as well as dev-master 563254c

Comment: Why do you need such a *"command-ception"*?

Comment: It's explained in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is what you need to do:

```
$args = $this->getNativeDefinition()->getArguments();
foreach ($args as $key => $arg) {
  if ($key === 'command') unset($args[$key]);
}
$this->getNativeDefinition()->setArguments($args);
$helpCommand = $this->getApplication()->get('help');
$helpCommand->run(new ArrayInput(['command_name' => $this->getName()]), $out);
return 0;
```

In my case I can just do the following as I do not have any arguments.

```
$this->getNativeDefinition()->setArguments([]);
```